# How to understand NPM [packages installed a lot] presentation

Tags: node.js, npm, package

When looking at npmjs.com welcome page,

You are presented
with a sort of 15 "Most popular packages".  To further understand the popularity of each one, I summarized the downloads (last month) of
each packages and came up with this graphic:

[image: Most popular packages]

For instance `Coffee-script package` last month downloads is
`2,478,652`.  After adding all those packages, I come up to a total `13,213,401` of downloads.

This graph shows that for `Coffee-script` for instance, `2,478,652/13,213,401` corresponds to `18,4% of downloads last month`, however the npm welcome page shows that `1,040,051,487 downloads` were done last month for the total of npm packages which bring the `18,4%` to `0,23%` `(2,478,652/1,040,051,487)` !
It seems that a lot of packages `[129,432-15=129,417; 99,9...%]` are not taken into account for a total of `[1,040,051,487 - 13,213,401 = 1,026,838,086; 98.73%]` of downloads last month.

**Question**: So amongst the (`98.73% of downloads` or `99,9% packages`) unmentioned in the welcome page, how can I focus on the most used packages ?

Comment: What's your use case? Are you just curious about the most downloaded packages?

Comment: I am curious and I want to focus on the most used packages.